# Specify List of Parameters in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have defined two Variables biases for weights and biases. How do I use those variables in Keras? Basically, what I am trying to do is as follows:

```
w = tf.get_variable("weight", shape=[784, 512], trainable=True)
b = tf.get_variable("bias", shape=[512], trainable=True)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,), weights=w, biases=b))
```

Does anyone know how to do this with Keras?

Comment: Just use ```model.trainable_variables```?

Comment: @iyop45 That only retrieves the list of variables.

Comment: and you can easily index that list: [v for v in model.trainable_variables if v.name == "weight:0"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a Numpy array directly, Keras will handle tensor conversion for you; also, `weights` handles both the 'regular' weights, and biases. Full example below:

```py
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np

input_shape = (784,)
dense_dim = 512

W = np.random.randn(input_shape[0], dense_dim)
b = np.random.randn(dense_dim)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(dense_dim, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape, weights=[W, b]))
```

Be sure to pass in the weights *in order which the layer expects them* - which can be inspected directly:

```py
print(model.layers[0].weights)
```

```py
[<tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(784, 512) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

---

**Set weights *after* building model**: use `layer.set_weights()`:

```py
model.layers[0].set_weights([W, b]) # again, mind the order
```

---

**Using tf.get_variable**: can't do; from `set_weights()` [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L1093), `K.batch_set_value` is used, which operates on raw array values rather than Tensors. If your goal is to track a layer's weight variables, you can simply fetch directly, and use `K.eval()` to get their values (or `.numpy()` for TF2):

```py
import keras.backend as K
dense1_weights, dense1_biases = model.layers[0].weights

if tf.__version__[0] == '2':
    print(dense1_weights.numpy())
else:
    print(K.eval(dense1_weights))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test this out. I'm surprised that this isn't in the documentation! https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense

Comment: @PeterSmith Keras/TF docs aren't perfect (and are often plain bad), but this time they're fine; as `weights` is in `kwargs`, it isn't standard practice to describe it in the class's docstring. You can see, however, that `Dense` inherits from `Layer`, which is defined in base_layer.py that I've linked - and it _is_ [described there](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/base_layer.py#L73).

Comment: I just tested this out. Do you know if there's a way to specify a TensorFlow tensor in the `weights` list instead of a NumPy array?